# Google charts - data from local json file - custom tooltips

Tags: json, file, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

I'm using google charts to create dvb-c channels availability charts.  The data for charts is red from local json file. The charts are working really fine, but I would like to add one feature to it, but I need some assistanse with it.

The feature I would like to add is custom tooltips, but I have no idea how to do it. I know I have to add the wanted data to json, but like I said Im not sure how to do it and how do I have to change my html code to make it work. I want tooltip to read local html file and show the content on tooltip.

Here is my html code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chart" style="width:3000px; height:600px;"></div> 
    </body>

    <script>
        // Visualization API with the 'corechart' package.
        google.charts.load('visualization', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

        function drawLineChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./avail.json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                var channels = [['Channel', 'HKI (%)', 'LTI (%)']];    // Define an array and assign columns for the chart.

                // Loop through each data and populate the array.
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    channels.push([value.Channel, value.HKI, value.LTI]);
                });

                // Set chart Options.
                var options = {
                    title: 'DVB-C Availability (HKI & LTI)',
                series: {
                    0: { color: '#ff3385', lineWidth: 5, pointSize: 5 },
                        1: { color: '#000000', lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 3},
                },
                vAxis: { "title": "Availability (%)", maxValue: 100 },
                hAxis : { "title": "Channels", showTextEvery:1, textStyle : {fontSize: 8, bold:'true' }, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45 },
                chartArea:{left:70,top:50,right:40,width:"90%",height:"70%"},
                tooltip: {isHtml: true, trigger: 'both'},
                    legend: { position: 'top', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14} } 
                };




                // Create DataTable and add the array to it.
                var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(channels)

                // Define the chart type (LineChart) and the container (a DIV in our case).
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(figures, options);      // Draw the chart with Options.
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert('Got an Error');
                }
            });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Here is little snippet of my current json file:

```
[
 { "Channel": "MTV Rocks", "HKI": 99.104700, "LTI": 98.760400 },
 { "Channel": "MTV3 HD", "HKI": 99.724600, "LTI": 99.724600 },
 { "Channel": "MTV3", "HKI": 100.000000, "LTI": 100.000000 },
]
```

Should I add something like this to json ?

```
[
{ "Channel": "MTV Rocks", "HKI": 99.104700, <object data="./hki1.html"></object> "LTI": 98.760400, <object data="./lti1.html"></object> },
{ "Channel": "MTV3 HD", "HKI": 99.724600, <object data="./hki1.html"></object>"LTI": 99.724600, <object data="./lti1.html"></object> },
{ "Channel": "MTV3", "HKI": 100.000000, object data="./hki1.html"></object>"LTI": 100.000000, object data="./lti1.html"></object> },
]
```

If this is the right way to change json, I have no idea how to change the html code to make this work.

Maybe someone can help me out with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, `'visualization'` is not a valid version number for google charts.
it looks the this was left over from the old library loader code.
use `'current'` instead...

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
```

next, you'll need to copy the html from the file into the json,
rather than trying to reference an external file.

the tooltip is only expecting an html snippet, not a full blown file.

to add the custom tooltip, first we need to add the column for the tooltip.
it should be an object, as follows...

```
{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}
```

if you want a tooltip for both `"HKI"` & `"LTI"`,
you need to add the above tooltip column after each column heading...

```
var channels = [['Channel', 'HKI (%)', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}, 'LTI (%)', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}]];
```

include the html when loading the rows...

```
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    channels.push([
      value.Channel,
      value.HKI,
      '<div>custom html goes here</div>',
      value.LTI,
      '<div>custom html goes here</div>'
    ]);
  });
```

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

function drawLineChart() {
  var data = [
   { "Channel": "MTV Rocks", "HKI": 99.104700, "LTI": 98.760400 },
   { "Channel": "MTV3 HD", "HKI": 99.724600, "LTI": 99.724600 },
   { "Channel": "MTV3", "HKI": 100.000000, "LTI": 100.000000 },
  ];

  var channels = [['Channel', 'HKI (%)', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}, 'LTI (%)', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}]];

  // Loop through each data and populate the array.
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    channels.push([
      value.Channel,
      value.HKI,
      '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div>' + value.Channel + '</div><div>' + value.HKI + '</div></div>',
      value.LTI,
      '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div>' + value.Channel + '</div><div>' + value.LTI + '</div></div>'
    ]);
  });

  // Set chart Options.
  var options = {
    title: 'DVB-C Availability (HKI & LTI)',
    series: {
      0: {color: '#ff3385', lineWidth: 5, pointSize: 5},
      1: {color: '#000000', lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 3},
    },
    vAxis: {title: "Availability (%)", maxValue: 100},
    hAxis : {title: "Channels", showTextEvery:1, textStyle : {fontSize: 8, bold:'true'}, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45},
    chartArea:{left: 70, top:50, right:40, width:"90%", height:"70%"},
    tooltip: {isHtml: true, trigger: 'both'},
    legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14}}
  };

  // Create DataTable and add the array to it.
  var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(channels)

  // Define the chart type (LineChart) and the container (a DIV in our case).
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(figures, options);      // Draw the chart with Options.
}
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
.ggl-tooltip div {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

if you want to display an external html file as the tooltip,
it may make sense to hide the standard tooltip,
and display the external file `'onmouseover'`

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

function drawLineChart() {
  var data = [
   { "Channel": "MTV Rocks", "HKI": 99.104700, "LTI": 98.760400 },
   { "Channel": "MTV3 HD", "HKI": 99.724600, "LTI": 99.724600 },
   { "Channel": "MTV3", "HKI": 100.000000, "LTI": 100.000000 },
  ];

  var channels = [['Channel', 'HKI (%)', 'LTI (%)']];

  // Loop through each data and populate the array.
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    channels.push([
      value.Channel,
      value.HKI,
      value.LTI
    ]);
  });

  // Set chart Options.
  var options = {
    title: 'DVB-C Availability (HKI & LTI)',
    series: {
      0: {color: '#ff3385', lineWidth: 5, pointSize: 5},
      1: {color: '#000000', lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 3},
    },
    vAxis: {title: "Availability (%)", maxValue: 100},
    hAxis : {title: "Channels", showTextEvery:1, textStyle : {fontSize: 8, bold:'true'}, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45},
    chartArea:{left: 70, top:50, right:40, width:"90%", height:"70%"},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14}}
  };

  // Create DataTable and add the array to it.
  var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(channels)

  // Define the chart type (LineChart) and the container (a DIV in our case).
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  var frame = document.getElementById('tooltip');

  // hide external html on mouse out
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function () {
    frame.className = 'hidden';
  });

  // display external html on mouse over
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (props) {
    if (props.row === null) {
      return;
    }

    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var bounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('point#' + (props.column - 1) + '#' + props.row);
    frame.style.left = bounds.left + 'px';
    frame.style.top = bounds.top + 'px';

    // replace this
    frame.src = 'https://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html';

    // with this
    //frame.src = '../' + figures.getColumnLabel(props.column) + (props.row + 1) + '.html';

    frame.className = 'tooltip';
  });

  chart.draw(figures, options);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<iframe class="hidden" id="tooltip"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat! 
I have 150 channels to monitor and all channels has two measuring points (two different data center). If bitrate goes under certain value it gets logged to the html file which was planned to use on tooltip. So, there is going to be 300 separate html files and Im pretty sure those are easiest to include on json file (correct me if Im wrong). Mysql/database usage is not an option here. I cannot introduce them the way you suggested on js script"'<div>custom html goes here</div>',".

Is there any other way than this ??:
var data = [
   { "Channel": "MTV Rocks", "HK.....

Comment: it may make sense to show the html file on the chart's `'onmouseover'` event, rather than in a custom tooltip...

Comment: Than you very much, I really do appreciate. Is there any way to do this the way that json has the url to errors for every channel (for both HKI and LTI)?

Comment: Maybe show only the link to the html file on tooltip ?

Comment: I managed to get this working.. I had to make the this part differenty : frame.src = '../' + figures.getColumnLabel(props.column) + (props.row + 1) + '.html';
Thank you very much Whitehat!